# Unable to push a 'New File' to a Specific Remote Git Branch

Tags: git, github

Unable to push a 'New File' to a specific 'Remote Git Branch'

1. I have created a new file locally.
2. I'm able to push the new local file to the remote branch called **master**.
3. But im not able to push the new local file to the other remote called **testBranch1**
4. Exception being recieved:

fatal: 'remotes/origin/testBranch1' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.*

Comment: What does `git remote show origin` say?

Comment: @Christoph i have added the output in my original post trail, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is

```
git push -u remoteName testBranch1
```

You have to give remote's name or URL.

Comment: thanks for the comment, i have added the following line of code but im afraid it didnt work, am i doing something wrong?

git push -u https://github.com/BagGianni/Test333.git testBranch1

Comment: even the following dosnt work:  git push -u https://github.com/BagGianni/Test333.git remotes/origin/testBranch1

Comment: You already have `origin` with URL https://github.com/BagGianni/Test333.git, so the syntax is `git push -u origin remotes/origin/testBranch1:testBranch1` (push a local remote-tracking branch to named remote branch). If that doesn't work: create a local branch from that remote-tracking and push it: `git checkout -b --track testBranch1 origin/testBranch1 && git push origin testBranch1`.